# SQL Query for retrieving Tags from

Tags: sql

I have standard tag model using three tables approach... Object, ObjectTag, Tag. So an Object can have multiple Tags.

Now, say I have a query that selecting Objects from given Tag = 'html':

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM Object o 
INNER JOIN ObjectTag ot ON ot.objectId = o.Id
INNER JOIN Tag t ON t.id = ot.tagId
WHERE t.name = 'html'
ORDER BY o.Id
```

So how can I use this query or results to get related tags. Meaning I want to get all other tags that each objects are associated with. So imagine I have the following results from the above query:

```
Object 1 ---> [html, apple]
Object 2 ---> [html, web, standard]
Object 3 ---> [html, coding]
```

So I want to get all other tags for the objects in this query:

```
[apple, web, standard, coding]
```

I can't seem to get my head around this.

Comment: Why not just remove the `WHERE t.name = 'html'` clause, so that you get all tags instead of just `html`?

Comment: It's because I need to get other tags that is related to 'html', meaning other objects that has html and any other tags...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct t.name
from ObjectTag ot join
     tags t
     on ot.tagId = t.id
where exists (select 1
              from ObjectTag ot2 join
                   Tags t2
                   on ot2.tagid = t2.id
              where ot.objectId = ot2.objectId and
                    t2.name = 'html' and t2.name <> t.name
             ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working... I am still testing it and will take as accepted.